# USB type C / Thunderbolt 3 compatibility

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, usb-c

USB type C and Thunderbolt 3 use the same plugs/cables/connectors.

While it is not possible for a computer with a USB-C port to connect to a Thunderbolt device, is it possible for a computer with a Thunderbolt port to connect with an USB-C device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the plug fits does not mean it will work.

A Thunderbolt device must connect with a Thunderbolt controller.  If the computer does not have Thunderbolt, then attaching a Thunderbolt device to it will not work even though the connector is the same.

The opposite is true, however.  If a computer has Thunderbolt, a USB device plugged into the Thunderbolt port will work.  The reason the plug design is the same is so that space can be saved on ultra-slim laptops by not having multiple ports.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on this slide from Intel, not all USB-C ports will be equal indeed..

[image: IDF 2015: Not all USB-C Omputer Ports will be equal]

Comment: If this image is trying to show the different symbols next to the port then that is hard to decipher with the resolution of the graphic.

Comment: Yes sorry about that you're right. I just uploaded a bigger image to my post